# WPF, simple way to assign value to TextBlock

Tags: wpf

I must, unfortunately, maintain an old WPF program.
In this program when a button is clicked, I calculate some values, and at the end, I must show a string composed of the values I calculate.

How to show the string?

I placed a TextBlock in the XAML, but how can assign my string to this TextBlock?
Can I do something like this `IdOfTheTextBlock.Text = mystring;`?

---

EDIT: Than you to everyone, bu everything is (as lot) more complicated.
The code where I can calculate values and compose the string can't "see" the textblock. This code is inside a procedure placed in a "model" and linked to a button in this way:

```
Command="{Binding Path=SyncAziendeCommand}"
```

where

```
SyncAziendeCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSyncAziende, () => DettagliEsito != null && !IsSync);
```

The real code in inside "OnSyncAziende", in another class and another file.

If i build a property in that class, can I link this property to a TextBlock like the procedure is linked to the button in the view?

Comment: Yes, you can after you have given the textblock a name. Did you just simply try it and run into an issue?

Comment: You can add a name to a TextBlock like this in xaml: TextBlock Text="SomeText" x:Name="MyTextBlock". And after this you shoul be able to use "MyTextBlock" in code behind. This is the approch if you are NOT using MVVM pattern and bindings.

Comment: @bazsisz Why can't you use this approach when using MVVM? Generally, it's valid MVVM.

Comment: @BionicCode I mean MVVM pattern was designed to seperate Model, View and ViewModel. By naming WPF FrameworkElements and handeling their logic in View violates MVVM pattern, because this kind of logic should be handled by ViewModel with bindings , INotifyPropertyChanged inteface, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When naming the element, it can be referenced from code-behind i.e. from within the name scope:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <TextBlock x:Name="ResultTextDisplay" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  
    this.ResultTextDisplay.Text = "Some string";
  }
}
```